# How can I set schema for EF Core when doing Tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, schema, migrate

I already have a context file and migrate folder with some files. It also works when I run the code. Now I want to have some tests to test repositories. And each test is isolate. So that means I have to create different database for each test and migrate, it is very waste time. So my solution is change schema before each test start. But I have created new schema and history table, but migrate not start. I guess maybe it not request Migration folder. But have tired many ways, not work for me. Could you help to review my code. Thanks.

```
public class TestsTearDown : IAsyncLifetime, IAsyncDisposable
    {
        // It uses to set different schema
        public string Schema { get; set; }

        public TestMyDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
        public MyDbContext SchemaDbContext { get; set; }

        // use to create database
        private readonly TestsBase testsBase;
        private static ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new NullLoggerFactory();

        public TestsTearDown(TestsBase testsBase)
        {
            this.TestsBase = testsBase;
        }

        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            await BuildTables();
        }

        private async Task BuildTables()
        {
            try
            {
                // Generate schema
                Schema = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace('-', '_');
                
                var options = BuildOptions(Schema);

                // This is connected by sa, have create permission
                SchemaDbContext = SqlDatabaseHandler.BuildDbContext(l1TestsBase.DatabaseName);

                // Create schema
                await SchemaDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"Create SCHEMA [{Schema}];");

                // Create new login and set default schema is just created
                var sql =
                    $"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT LOGINNAME from SYS.SYSLOGINS WHERE NAME = 'sa_{Schema}') CREATE LOGIN sa_{Schema} WITH PASSWORD='Value*12', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON;IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NAME FROM SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS WHERE NAME = 'sa_{Schema}' and default_schema_name = '{Schema}') CREATE USER sa_{Schema} FOR LOGIN sa_{Schema} WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[{Schema}];ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER sa_{Schema};";
                await SchemaDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql);

                // Build Context by new Login
                DbContext = BuildTestDbContext(options, Schema);
                // Do migrate, nothing happened here and no exception
                DbContext.Database.Migrate();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        async Task IAsyncLifetime.DisposeAsync()
        {
            await DisposeAsync();
        }

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            // await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
            //     $"DROP TABLE [{Schema}].[__EFMigrationsHistory]");
            // await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync((string)$"DROP SCHEMA [{Schema}]");
            await DbContext.DisposeAsync();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private static TestMyDbContext BuildTestDbContext(DbContextOptions options, string schema)
        {
            return new TestMyDbContext(
                options,
                new TestCurrentUserName(),
                new TestPersistenceConfiguration(),
                loggerFactory,
                schema);
        }

        private DbContextOptions BuildOptions(string schema)
        {
            return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestMyDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(SqlDatabaseHandler.BuildSchemaConnectionStringForDatabase(TestsBase.DatabaseName, schema),
                    builder => builder.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", schema))
                .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(CoreEventId.ManyServiceProvidersCreatedWarning))
                .Options;
        }
    }
```

TestMyDbContext.cs

```
public class TestMyDbContext : DbContext, IPersistenceMigration
    {
        public string Schema { get; }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public TestMyDbContext(
            DbContextOptions dbContextOptions,
            IGetCurrentUsername getCurrentUsername,
            IPersistenceConfiguration configuration,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, string schema)
            : base(dbContextOptions)
        {
            this.getCurrentUsername = getCurrentUsername;
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
            Schema = schema;
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating([NotNull] ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Schema);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(TestMyDbContext).Assembly);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring([NotNull] DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            if (configuration.EnableLogging) builder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
            builder.ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory>();
        }
```

DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory.cs

```
public class DynamicModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
    {
        public object Create(DbContext context) => new SchemaModelCache(context);
    }

    class SchemaModelCache : ModelCacheKey
    {
        private readonly string schema;
        public SchemaModelCache(DbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            schema = context is TestMyDbContext dbContext ? dbContext.Schema : string.Empty;
        }

        protected override bool Equals(ModelCacheKey other)
            => base.Equals(other) && (other as SchemaModelCache)?.schema == schema;

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = base.GetHashCode() * 397;
            if (schema != null)
            {
                hashCode ^= schema.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This not gonna work because the schema is part of the database model/migrations, hence you'll need new migration for each schema. Also `DbContext.Database.Migrate();` won't do anything as it executes only the migration code generated at design time with EF Core tools (e.g. `Add-Migration` command). You really need to use separate database, because the database name (from connection string) and type are not part of the migrations, hence ``DbContext.Database.Migrate();` will create/update the specified database to the latest version.

Comment: O, Thank you, by the way, since use separate database is very slow, is there any good way to have tests.

Comment: @Tommy the propably best way is not to create new databases/schemas but just have a single database and schema and clear all the tables before each test